# Cell reference is out of range - But I use GetDataRange()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried a bunch of solution but it always end with Cell ref is out of range.

I thought that `GetDataRange()` & `GetLastRow()` would cover the last non-blank cell but I'm stuck. I've tried to hardcode my cell values (from X to Y) but nothing seems to change.

```
var course; 
var searchingCol; 

function CalculateFurnitureList()
{
  GetCourseString(); 
  FindColumnNumber(course); 
  GetSpecialFurnituresValue(); 
}

function GetCourseString()
{
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var courseType = activeSheet.getRange("A2").getValue();
  Browser.msgBox('Generate furniture list for ' + courseType + ' course');

  course = courseType;  
}

function FindColumnNumber(ct)
{
  var furnitureSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MaterielCours"); 
  var range = furnitureSheet.getDataRange(); 
  var width = range.getWidth();

  //Search every cell in the designated area to find the course name
  for (var i = 1; i <= width; i++)
  {
    var data = range.getCell(1,i); 
    if (data.getValue() == ct)
    {
      Browser.msgBox('Trouvé ! ' + data.getValue() + ' se trouve en : ' + i +':1');
      searchingCol = i; 
    }
  }
}

function GetSpecialFurnituresValue()
{
  Browser.msgBox(searchingCol); 

  var furnitureSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("MaterielCours"); 
  var range = furnitureSheet.getDataRange();
  var length = range.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 1; i < length; i++)
  {
    var data = range.getCell(searchingCol, i); 
    if (data.getValue() !== "")
    {
      // Do nothing
    }
    else
    {
      if (data == "Abs")
      {
        Browser.msgBox('NTM');
      }
      else
      {
        // Calculate value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's 
`var data = range.getCell(searchingCol, i);`
in `GetSpecialFurnituresValue()` which causes the problem.

The weird thing is that the same process in `FindColumnNumber` is working perfectly.

Comment: chances are the range doesn't represent the indexes

Comment: What line is the error on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(editing my original answer - I must have been tired!)  In the function GetSpecialFurnitureValues, there are a few things.

The for loop uses i < length, but it should be <= or you will miss the last row:

```
// for (var i = 1; i < length; i++)  
for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++)
```

Your column/rows were simply reversed. :)

```
// var data = range.getCell(searchingCol, i);   
var data = range.getCell(i, searchingCol);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Good catch.  I totally missed that.